# What fallacy is it when someone accuses an entire group of hypocrisy, instead of taking into account individual opposing ideas?

Tags: fallacies

For example -

"You all claim to want women's liberation, yet you bully women into shaving. Therefore you don't truly want women's liberation."

It's unlikely these contradictory actions/thoughts are coming from mostly the same group of people. This person is perceiving a difference in attitude throughout many individuals, has combined these people into one group of hypocrites, and has concluded that everyone is ingenuine.

Is there a specific name for this fallacy?

Comment: Ascribing traits to individuals based on the group they belong to is called [stereotyping](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Stereotype#As_a_logical_fallacy). Whether it is a fallacy depends on how the grouping is done, what kind of trait is ascribed, (in particular, whether it is related to the grouping method), and whether the ascribing is probabilistic. In this example, it is unclear what the group addressed is, and "you all" is a rhetorical flourish that typically does not mean "all" literally.

Comment: I left out of the example a specific group on purpose, because this argument tends to be seen in isolated online posts, addressing an audience. These type of posts are common on Tumblr, so I suppose the group is Tumblr users. But this is such a large and diverse group of people that I don't think stereotyping applies. What is fallacious to me is that they have fabricated a group of same-minded people that probably don't exist, if that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This person is perceiving a difference in attitude throughout many individuals, has combined these people into one group of hypocrites, and has concluded that everyone is ingenuine.

Concluding that what is true of some (or even many) is therefore true of the whole is to commit the [fallacy of composition](https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/logicalfallacies/Fallacy-of-Composition).

Answer (score -1):

Groups can be held responsible for actions because groups are formed based on some belief system and from those belief emanates the actions of individuals. Examples of belief system based groups are scientific community, Islam , Hinduism, Christianity , Buddhism, caste of people like Brahmans , class of people like bourgeois or worker class , nations etc … These groups hold beliefs like “only physical evidence can prove something to be true” or “male are superior to women” or “Money is all that that matters” etc ..,

Based on the group, individuals perform actions. Those actions might expose the conditioned delusions of group. So the entire group is blamed for the individuals action and result is something like Islamiphobia or anti-capitalism or anti-atheism etc.

No word comes to my mind for such a general behaviour. But you can make words by prefixing Anti- before the group like Anti-science, Anti-Islam or Anti-Christians or Anti-captitalist etc.

Comment: Groups can not really be held accountable for actions as groups are more or less interpersonal relations, so the ones that are held responsible for the actions of a group are individual whether that fits or not. Also you list a bunch of very different groups like in some cases the group emerges from a belief system of it's constituents, but in other cases a "group" is implied by an outsider but people within that categorization might not have any relation to each other and might not agree with a shared believe system and it's usually the individual creating the group not the other way around

Comment: @haxor789 In some cases individuals give birth to group and in other cases group give birth to individuals and in some cases individuals have nothing to do with any group. Sometimes groups are held responsible (whether it is right or not is another matter) sometimes individuals are held responsible.

Comment: In all cases individuals are held responsible as "groups" don't exist on their own. In some cases all individuals of a group are held responsible and in some cases it's just a selected few of them, but in either cases it's individuals rather than groups being held responsible. Also members of the scientific community might very well believe in non-physical things, it's just that science itself can't really do anything with them unless they are physical so they are usually excluded (the topics not the people) from the discussion because of that.

Comment: @haxor789 I know that groups are forced to slavery or extradited or divided or outcasted for their expression through individuals who reflect the ideology of groups. It is a good idea to hold only individuals responsible but that always doesn’t happen in reality.

Comment: Hi Dheeraj, yes anti- is a good word that describes that sentiment, but I meant accusations of hypocrisy specifically. An example using religious groups would be -
"Christians say God loves gay people, yet they refuse wedding services to gay couples. Therefore they are all homophobes." In this case, the arguer has combined christian LGBT allies with christian homophobes, and has treated them all as the exact same people. The arguer has ignored that there is variation between christians, and has assumed this variation of opinion is a shared hypocrisy throughout all christians.